# Useful posts about FFmpeg are spread over four sites

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, search, migration

Good and useful posts about [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) are spread over four sites. A few examples:

- Stack Overflow

  *[FFmpeg - Multiple videos with 4 areas and different play times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515833/ffmpeg-multiple-videos-with-4-areas-and-different-play-times)* 
  *[FFmpeg - Overlay one video onto another video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video)*
  (these questions are not language-specific, but rather general-purpose FFmpeg)
- Super User

  *[Delayed video overlay using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/734234/delayed-video-overlay-using-ffmpeg)*
- Video Production

  [1717 questions tagged [ffmpeg]](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg)
- Unix & Linux

  Some questions are indeed Linux-specific, such as *[Install ffmpeg on debian with apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632688/install-ffmpeg-on-debian-with-apt)*, but many others are "general" FFmpeg questions:

  *[How to remove an audio track from an mp4 video file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-remove-an-audio-track-from-an-mp4-video-file)*

which sometimes makes it difficult to perform searches.

**Where is the recommended place to ask new general FFmpeg questions?**

Is there a way to centralize all questions/answers about FFmpeg across these four sites, to make it easier for readers to search?

(I guess it would be question migration, but this would be difficult for thousands of questions/answers?)

Or maybe the answer to my question is just *"If it ain't broke don't fix it"*, I don't know.

Comment: The suggested duplicate perfectly answers: "Is there a way to centralize all questions/answers about ffmpeg across these 4 sites, to make it easier for readers to search?". So in that regard it applies perfectly.

Comment: Again, this can be part of an answer @Luuklag, but here this discussion is really specific to a pattern happening for a specific widely-used tag, please don't close as dupe. I think this specific tag [ffmpeg] needs attention on its own.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to centralize all questions/answers about ffmpeg across these 4 sites, to make it easier for readers to search?

There already is: You can use the search option on stackexchange.com to find ffmpeg questions on any site, [like this](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bffmpeg%5D+is%3Aq).

> Where is the recommended place to ask new general ffmpeg questions?

On the site where they would be most on-topic. This is the most important, and you shouldn't bypass that for any of the things I'm going to list hereafter.

You might also want to take into account things like general traffic: more new questions might mean your question quietly disappears without getting much attention. Or, you might look at recently asked ffmpeg questions on a site to see whether they have answers: If they have, there are probably a few users around to help you with your problem too. If every recent question has gone unanswered, well... the community might not have people to answer ffmpeg questions.

Comment: ffmpeg is a bit of a beast as it is a powerful toolchain that has both an end-user side as a programming / api / automation side. Under the hood it is all the same fmpeg which might  cause confusion as you will find a question on say de-interlacing on all sites but depending on your usage scenario only a specific site might fit. Other examples of such tools are imagemagick and curl.

Comment: @rene Exactly, for example on unix.SE, you can find both unix/linux-specific ffmpeg questions such as *"Install ffmpeg on debian with apt"*, but also general purpose questions such as *"How to remove an audio track from an mp4 video file?"* (see my original post for links and discussion about this).